# MemoryStream PDF file in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0

Keep getting an error 'Cannot access a closed Stream.'

Does the file need to be physically saved on a server first, prior to being Streamed? I am doing the same with Excel file and it works just fine. Trying to use the same principle here with PDF file.

```
    [HttpGet("ExportPdf/{StockId}")]
    public IActionResult ExportPdf(int StockId)
    {
        string fileName = "test.pdf";

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

       // Create PDF document  
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 25, 25);

        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);

        document.Open();
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
        document.Close();

        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        return File(memoryStream, "application/pdf", fileName);
    }
```

Comment: Try `memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)`

Comment: @tchelidze that's what the OP is already doing. `Position` works fine

Comment: Check the documentation for `PdfWriter.Close()` maybe it's disposing the stream you are using.

Comment: `document.Close();` probably closes the stream as well. Check for an overload that *doesn't* close the stream too

Comment: @tchelidze tried Try memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin) same error

Comment: Probably not a best workaround, but try `var stream = new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray()); document.Close(); return File(stream, ....)`

Comment: try process the  file before returning it like @tchelidze said. Also wrap your Memorystream in a using() so that takes care of disposing  it. Never used pdfwritter but your closing that reasorce before the parent stream. Ttry a 'using(var memorystream = new MemorySteam)`

Answer (score 1):

Switched to iText& (7.1.1) version as per David Liang comment

Here is the code that worked for me, a complete method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Pdf()
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(memoryStream);

        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);

        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Welcome"));
        document.Close();

        byte[] file = memoryStream.ToArray();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        ms.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
        ms.Position = 0;

        return File(fileStream: ms, contentType: "application/pdf", fileDownloadName: "test_file_name" + ".pdf");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `iText7`? If yes, please add that tag onto your question.

```
using (var output = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(output))
    {
        // You need to set this to false to prevent the stream
        // from being closed.
        pdfWriter.SetCloseStream(false);

        using (var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter))
        {
            ...
        }

        var renderedBuffer = new byte[output.Position];
        output.Position = 0;
        output.Read(renderedBuffer, 0, renderedBuffer.Length);

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I switched to iText7, really appreciate it!